# Change \baselineskip to match other fontsize than currently used

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, baseline

I want to increase the `\baselineskip` size to the one used with `\normalsize`. So if I use a `\tiny` size, I want the spacing between the lines to match the spacing between the lines in `\normalsize`. I don't want to adjust it absolutely but depending on the fontsize used for the whole document.

[image: MWE image]

MWE with `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
{\tiny this is a tiny text example.
    It shouldn't be too short to see the linebreaks.
    This is the usual \verb|\baselineskip|.

    This is happening without a \verb|\par|.
    Anyhow, I want this \verb|\baselineskip| independently of a \verb|\par|\dots.%
}

Just some usual text. %This \baselineskip should be used for the tiny part too
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just save and restore the baselineskip:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
{\skip0=\baselineskip\tiny\baselineskip=\skip0 this is a tiny text example.
    It shouldn't be too short to see the linebreaks.
    This is the usual \verb|\baselineskip|.

    This is happening without a \verb|\par|.
    Anyhow, I want this \verb|\baselineskip| independently of a \verb|\par|\dots.%
}

Just some usual text. %This \baselineskip should be used for the tiny part too
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Although in my eyes this looks horrible, here is a way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\fontsize{5}{\the\baselineskip}\selectfont%tiny with normalsizes baselineskip
\lipsum[1]

\normalsize
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The above idea with a little more automation (that allows you to keep the actual text untouched, i.e. to be able to just write `\tiny` etc. in the body):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\defaultbaselineskip{\ifcase\@ptsize 12\or 13.6\or 14.5\else 12\fi}
\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{\@nomath#1%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\let\@currsize#1\fi
  \fontsize{#2}{\defaultbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\tiny
\lipsum[1]

\normalsize
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And even fancier (requires compiling twice):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \newwrite\defbslfile
    \immediate\openout\defbslfile=\jobname.bsl
    \immediate\write\defbslfile{\noexpand\def\noexpand\defaultbaselineskip{\the\baselineskip}}
  \fi
  \immediate\closeout\defbslfile
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bsl}{%
    \def\@setfontsize##1##2##3{\@nomath##1%
      \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\let\@currsize##1\fi
      \fontsize{##2}{\ifdefined\defaultbaselineskip\defaultbaselineskip\else\@xiipt\fi}\selectfont}%
  }{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\tiny
\lipsum[1]

\normalsize
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree for this case, but if you have two boxes next to each other with different sizes, it is handy. Moreover the size difference is not that big, just used it for the MWE.

Comment: @nox -- sure, in the case you described it might be a cool feature.